# Только числа, в т.ч. отрицательные

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, oracle12c

Не могу составить регулярное выражение, которое определяет отрицательное число. Задача определить только те строки, в которых число < 0. Но при этом в анализируемом текстовом поле может быть что угодно.

```
select regexp_replace('3696360-ДПО3','[^-[[:digit:]]]*') from dual
```

Составил такое выражение, но оно оставляет "-" даже в центре. Как сформировать правильное выражение?

Немного поправлю: нужно оставлять и сравнивать только нормальные числа (-10, -ХХ), а всякий мусор игнорировать. То есть выражение

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_replace('3696360-ДПО3','[^-[[:digit:]]]*')<0
```

ничего не должно вернуть, а выражение

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_replace('-20','[^-[[:digit:]]]*')<0
```

вернуть строку

Comment: если будет такой текст `ДПО3-3696360` - это отрицательное число?

Comment: Всегда ли в строке только одно отрицательное число? Если да, `regexp_replace('3696360-ДПО3','.*(-[0-9]+).*', '\1')`. Или `regexp_substr('3696360-ДПО3', '-[0-9]+')`

Comment: @Denis - нет, отрицательные числа всегда начинаются с - (-1, -133).

Comment: @Wiktor - да, нужно отобрать только строки с нормальными отрицательными числами

Comment: "Нормальными"? А пример таких и ненормальных можно?

Comment: @Wiktor - select regexp_replace('3696360-ДПО3','.*(-[0-9]+).*','\1') from dual - оставляет все выражение. Нормальные - и цифры (-1, -139), ненормальные )) - как в примере, но они должны игнорироваться. А не игнорироваться только нормальные (-10, -ХХ)

Comment: Так мы никогда не договоримся. *Дано*: `'3696360-ДПО3', '-30ДПО3', '-0ДПО3', 'ДПО3-56ДПО3-60ДПО3'`. Каков ожидаемый результат?

Comment: @Wiktor - да, извините. Описал требуемое в вопросе. Оставляем для сравнения только -1, -ХХ - нормальные числа, все остальное не сравнивается

Comment: Вроде, `regexp_replace('-20','.*(-[1-9][0-9]*).*', '\1')` [подходит](https://rextester.com/GBOXQF1568). Что не так?

Comment: @Wiktor - Да, но оно вызывает ошибку в запросе при такой проверке select 1 from dual where regexp_replace('3696360-ДПО3','.*(-[1-9][0-9]*).*', '\1') < 0. Так как возвращает весь текст, а должно вернуть null

Comment: А почему тогда `select 1 from dual where regexp_substr('3696360-ДПО3','-[1-9][0-9]*')<0` не подходит?

Comment: @Wiktor - Да, Виктор, вроде подходит. Спасибо, буду проверять.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86374/discussion-between---and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `REGEXP_SUBSTR` вместо `REGEXP_REPLACE`, чтобы найти отрицательное число.

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_substr('3696360-ДПО3','-[1-9][0-9]*')<0
```

Тут `-[1-9][0-9]*` находит минус, цифру от `1` до `9` и затем 0 и более любых цифр, и найденное значение возвращается функцией `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Возможно, `-[0-9]+` будет достаточно: минус, за которым следует 1 и более цифр.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку все отрицательные числа начинаются с минуса, надо порсто проверять на соответствие регулярке `-\d+`.